# bootstrap 4 with toggle giving a maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, toggle

I'm working in asp.net.  Bootstrap 4, Jquery 3.3.1 trying to use the bootstrap4-toggle.  I have 3 inputs each with their own specific ID.  On load the first toggle is turned on.  I have an on change event that fires whenever a checkbox is changed.  In this change event if i do either:

```
$("#chk15849").bootstrapToggle('off');
// or 
$("#chk15849").prop('checked', false).change();
```

I get an error telling me

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Looking up how to perform this action it appears I'm doing it correctly.. but since I'm getting the error apparently I'm not.  Here is some sample code

Here is the fiddle of what I'm doing.  http://jsfiddle.net/4x5r09fv/

```
$('[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  $("#chk15849").bootstrapToggle('off');
  //$("#chk15849").prop('checked', false).change();
})
})
```

Both of these examples result in the Uncaught Range Error

This is me starting simple working up to a more complex page.  But for now, I need to get this figured out.

You'll see when you run the fiddle that on load the first toggle is turned on.  When the second toggle is clicked, the change event fires and the first toggle is turned off.  This is when the error happens to look in Chrome's dev tools.

Any help would be great.

--Additional information.

Aswin Kumar provided a solution. But building on what he said.  What if this is more dynamic.  So if the number of toggles changes and we want to have all toggles to off except for the one turned on.  How is this done.  I found this code

```
  $(".toggle").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('[id^="toggle"]').not(this).each(function () {
                    $(this).bootstrapToggle('off');
                });
            }
        });
```

However, this code starts out the same as mine and also give the "Uncaught RangeError:Maximum call stack size exceeded".  Once again, i'm not sure how to change the code so that it doesn't give the error and allows for the toggle of all except one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured this out.  First, since i'm working in asp.net, i wanted to be able to get the status of the checkbox from code behind.  So the checkbox that is created in a data driven listview i made the checkboxes look like this.

```
<input id="test" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" runat="server" data-on="It's <br/> Working" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
```

To handle the toggle of making only one checkbox be checked in javascript looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#ListDiv [type=checkbox]").change(function () {
            console.log("first if");
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                console.log("second if");
                $("#ListDiv [type=checkbox]").not(this).each(function () {
                    console.log("third one");
                    $(this).bootstrapToggle('off');
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

ListDiv is the name of my div surrounding the listview.  It makes it so that the toggle only effects the checkboxes within the div tag.  As far as code behind goes to see what the state of the checkbox is.. that is handled with

```
  For Each i As ListViewItem In Me.lvClassIndex.Items
        CType(i.FindControl("lbl"), Label).Text = CType(i.FindControl("test"), HtmlInputCheckBox).Checked.ToString
    Next
```

This was a test page so i was taking the value of the checkbox in each row and putting the results in a label in the same row.  But it works pretty well.  If there are over 100 rows returned it starts to get a little slow, but this works well for what i was after.